# Nested component re-render with preact signals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact, preact-signal

I have a `activeWindows` signal defined **outside** the JSX:

```
export const activeWindows = signal([
  {
    index: 1,
    title: 'App1',
    isMinimized: false,
    dimensions: {
        ...
    },
  {
    index: 2,
    title: 'App2',
    isMinimized: false,
    dimensions: {
      ...
    }
  },

  ....
  }
```

In my parent component:

```
      {
        activeWindows.value.map((window) => (
            <Fragment key={window.index}>
              <AppWindow 
                idx={window.index}
                title={window.title}
                isMinimized={window.isMinimized}
                dimensions={window.dimensions}
                handleClose={() => handleClose(window.index)}
              />
            </Fragment>
        ))
      }
```

handleClose is just removing the given window object from activeWindows:

```
  function handleClose(index: any){
    activeWindows.value = activeWindows.value.filter((window) => (
      window.index != index
    ))
  }
```

In my AppWindow, handling of handleClose is very straight-forward. On a button click, it is just executing  the method.

Now, the main issue arises when my handleClose is clicked but the re-render is not trigerred everytime. It happens **alternatively**, if for first window, if it re-rendered then for the second it doesn't then for third it works and so on. At those cases when UI is not re-rendered, my removed object's window is still visible in UI. Its visible until there is any other trigger that can push a re-render. Why is this happening? Even upon successful updation of my `activeWindows`, I dont have a successful re-render.

I made lot of hits and trials but none seem to work.

Comment: One workaround I discovered myself, is executing `ref.current.remove()` before executing `handleClose` method where `ref` is a reference to the element returned by the component. Not sure if this is very reliable or even a good way

Comment: I wonder if you have hit a race condition, your closing the same control your clicking on,.. One idea is to defer the close, maybe `handleClose={() => setTimeout(() => handleClose(window.index))}`

Comment: @Keith Is it even possible to hit race without any asynchronous execution? There are no API calls or useState calls in the whole scenario

Comment: @Keith I tried setTimeout, it doesn't seems to work